# How to restrict the drag and drop area in a canvas

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, drag-and-drop

I have  a canvas,lets say of dimensions 500x600.I have some controls inside that canvas.User can rearrange the controls by drag and drop.But I want to restrict the drag and drop within that canvas.

For example:There is a button in the canvas.User can drag and drop the button anywhere inside the canvas.But if the user tries to drag the button out of the canvas boundaries,it should stick  in the canvas boundary.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

The signature for `startDrag()` is `public function startDrag(lockCenter:Boolean = false, bounds:Rectangle = null):void`

The second parameter allows you to pass a `Rectangle` to act as bounds for your `DisplayObject`. It won't be dragged outside of this

Comment: I am using DragManager for dragging because I need the proxy image and also I need to carry some data while dragging.Using startDrag() I cannot achieve these two unless I write code for that.Any solutions for fixing the drag boundary while using DragManager.doDrag?

Comment: Hm, I've not used the `DragManager` in Flex, but looking quickly at it it doesn't seem to allow for bounds, which sucks. In that case, I'd either rewrite the functionality myself to allow for `startDrag()` with an image and data, or I'd use feedback to indicate that you're outside of the bounds. Something like highlight the canvas in green when you're good, and in red when you're outside of the bounds.

Comment: Hmmm.I think adding dragproxy and dragSource to startDrag would be an extra overhead.Needs to figure out some other way. :) :)
Regarding highlighting the canvas,that is not the feedback I really want to give to the user back.The controls are within the canvas itself and so what I really want is that the user is restricted to move around the controls within the canvas area

Answer (score 0):

You should catch MouseDown event on the target controls and then subscribe MouseMove event. In MouseMove handler you should get Canvas and control's rectangles (in the same coordinate space) and use `containsRect()` method (documentation is [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Rectangle.html?filter_flex=4.5&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2.5#containsRect%28%29)) to determine if control is still within Canvas. If it goes out you shouldn't move it.

And don't remember unsubscribe your MouseMove event on MouseUp!

Comment: I am using DragManager.doDrag for drag and drop.I was thinking of adding a dragExit event handler for the canvas.dragExit will be fired when the dragged object moves out of the canvas.In the event handler i have to do 'something' to prevent the dragging.This 'something' I am not able to figure out.

Comment: I suppose the answer from @divillysausages will solve your problem.