# limiting Mouse Movement

Tags: actionscript-3

In a certain event, I need my mouse movement to be limited.so far I have tried using this method....

I just Gave it a range ti needs to stay under...

```
if (100 < mouseX < 200 &&  100 < mouseY < 200) {
...
}
else
{
trace ("not between the boundary");
}
```

but it doesn't seem to work at all. I cannot let the mouse escape the area between 100 and 200 horizontally and 100 to 200 vertically.

Can anybody please help me on how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ActionScript, you cannot chain multiple comparators in that way. You must break the comparison up into two steps.

Instead of:

`100 < mouseX < 200 &&  100 < mouseY < 200`

you must use:

`100 < mouseX && mouseX < 200 &&  100 < mouseY && mouseY < 200`

Answer (score 0):

There was a questiong about this already, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868111/restrict-mouse-move-area-in-a-flex-application), it states there you cannot limit mouse movement at all. In your case, you can create a custom object that will follow the mouse cursor while hiding the cursor itself, thus "faking" the mouse cursor, and for that object you can limit its movement by constraining its X&Y coordinates. And yes, no chaining of compare operators in ActionScript.

```
var mcCursor:MovieClip; // assign this to a proper asset
...
function onMouseMove(e:MouseEvent):void {
    mcCursor.x=e.stageX; // assuming mcCursor to be placed directly on stage above all
    mcCursor.y=e.stageY;
    if (mcCursor.x<100) mcCursor.x=100;
    if (mcCursor.x>200) mcCursor.x=200;
    if (mcCursor.y<100) mcCursor.y=100;
    if (mcCursor.y>200) mcCursor.y=200;
}
```

And then, when you parse mouse clicks, check if `mcCursor` is in a proper position, if not, just don't react on the click (`return` from listener).

Comment: oh awesome sorry for my bad wording I did mean to say I wanted to fake it. Thx a lot for the answer :D